# Javascript post array and receive it in serverside

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I'm trying to send array using ajax, imagine the array

```
var anotherOne = 'anotherOneData';
var documents = ['banana', 'apple', 'monkey'];
```

I sent these normal value and array to server-side, using ajax, no problem with got this in server side,

```
console.log(req.body);

//result (anotherOne is I sent too, this is not array,)
{ anotherOne : 'anotherOneData',
  'documents[]': 
[ 'banana', 
'apple, 
'monkey' ] }
```

How can I access documents's first element?

```
req.body.documents[0] // not working
req.body.documents[0][0] // not working
req.body.documents instanceof Array // false : why?
```

I'm totally couldn't get what's going on, Please help me.

Comment: Could you post the code you're using to submit the AJAX call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've logged, the property on `req.body` is called `documents[]`, so:

```
console.log(req.body['documents[]'][0]);
```

That said, I think I'd send it as JSON and then parse it on the server.